# How can you retrieve multiple GET variables from a query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, get

I am passing `GET` variables between two ASP.NET websites. In the past I have always used `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["VARIABLE_NAME"]` or `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["VARIABLE_NAME"]` to read a variable from the query string, but I now have the need to pass two distinct variables in my query string, like so:

http://sampleurl.com/Default.aspx?VariableA=ValueA?VariableB=ValueB

My problem is that `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["VariableA"]` will return the entire query string starting with `VariableA` and continuing on through `VariableB`.

I could get the entire query string, split it on the variable names, and then read the resulting values, but that seems sloppy. Is there a more elegant solution to reading multiple `GET` variables via C#?

Comment: Your URL isn't constructed properly. The querystring starts with the `?` but then each key-value pair has to be separated with an ampersand (`&`) and not more question marks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try like this

```
sampleurl.com/Default.aspx?VariableA=ValueA&VariableB=ValueB
```

You have seperate query string variable with ampersand(&). ? starts the query string, = separates a name from it's value, and & separates name/value pairs.

Comment: The important detail is that `?` starts the query string, `=` separates a name from it's value, and `&` separates name/value pairs, not another `?`.

Comment: nice description  @CoreyOgburn

Comment: The asker didn't seem to understand the structure of a query string, and I had to look twice to notice the difference between your url and the one in the question because the differences were so small. I just wanted to spotlight those differences.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks all for humoring me. I was not aware of that the & separated variables. Thanks again.